# Unable to printf floating point numbers from executable shared library

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries

I'm developing a shared library which can be executed independently to print it's own version number.

I've defined a custom entry point as:

```
const char my_interp[] __attribute__((section(".interp"))) = "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2";

void my_main() {
   printf("VERSION: %d\n", 0);
   _exit(0);
}
```

and I compile with

```
gcc -o list.os -c -g -Wall -fPIC list.c
gcc -o liblist.so -g -Wl,-e,my_main -shared list.os -lc
```

This code **compiles** and **runs** perfectly.

My issue is when I change the parameter of the printf to be a float or double (%f or %lf). The library will then compile but **segfault** when run.

Anyone have any ideas?

***edit1:***

Here is the code that segfaults:

```
const char my_interp[] __attribute__((section(".interp"))) = "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"; 

void my_main() { 
    printf("VERSION: %f\n", 0.1f); 
    _exit(0); 
}
```

***edit2:***

Additional environmental details:

```
uname -a
```

Linux mjolnir.site 3.1.10-1.16-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jun 27 05:21:40 UTC 2012 (d016078) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
gcc --version
```

gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.6.2

```
/lib64/libc.so.6
```

Configured for x86_64-suse-linux.
Compiled by GNU CC version 4.6.2.
Compiled on a Linux 3.1.0 system on 2012-03-30.

***edit 3:***

Output in /var/log/messages upon segfault:

Aug 11 08:27:45 mjolnir kernel: [10560.068741] liblist.so[11222] general protection ip:7fc2b3cb2314 sp:7fff4f5c7de8 error:0 in libc-2.14.1.so[7fc2b3c63000+187000]

Comment: This works perfectly on my 32 bits machine. And it should work on 64 bits too. did you include <unistd.h> and <stdio.h>?

Comment: @TOC I did. Did you try print a floating point number as the version number? The code I posted works fine, except when printing a float.

Comment: Can you show the code that prints the float?

Comment: @kobrien : Yes the code works fine on Linux (32 bits) for float and double

Comment: I get the same problem as you. And if I use -m32 with the obvious modification on .interp, it works. I've attempted to add -lm in case it made a difference, but that wasn't the problem. I've also added the missing includes, they could make a difference as printf is variadic, but it wasn't the case.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Question updated as requested.

Comment: probably this is not your problem, `%f` is for `double` and `%lf` is for `long double`. There is no format for `float` since these are converted to `double` anyhow for variadic functions like `printf`.

Comment: @kobrien what about bt inside gdb?

Comment: As long as there isn't a prototype for `printf()` that says the second argument is a float, then the float should be promoted to double anyway.  But I'd certainly be curious to know if it works 'better' (without crashing) if you use `0.1` instead of `0.1f`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, it doesn't (my tentative was with 0.0 before the OP gave his code).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Crashes on 0.1 and 0.1f.

Comment: @TOC backtrace doesn't show anything up. I've all relevant debug symbols compiled in. Still get "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a9b314 in ?? ()"

Comment: Is the problem that `stdout` isn't set up by the start-up code in this context?  Normally in an executable, a file such as `crt0.o` is included which deals with setup work such as ensuring `stdout` is available?

Comment: I tried it, and other printfs work OK, for example with %s. Also, other floating-point operations, such as sin and cos, work OK. It's just printing floating-point numbers that doesn't work. Perhaps it is that some part of the C library isn't loaded properly?

Comment: It's reasonable to assume this is down to a missing initialization of stdout. I shall do some sleuthing.

Comment: Another thing: When it crashes, this message gets printed to the system log: Aug 11 09:08:28 bimbatron kernel: [69291.763774] liblist.so[6839] general protection ip:7fcba4478064 sp:7fffaa66af78 error:0 in libc-2.13.so[7fcba4427000+18a000]

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy I can confirm that happens on my machine too. As of yet, people are suggesting recreating  /dev/null as a solution, but that seems hackish and unsatisfactory.

Comment: This appears to be the class of error occuring: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_protection_fault

Comment: "Recreating /dev/null as a solution"? I don't understand that at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out. :)

The floating point operations on x86_64 use the xmm vector registers. Access to these must be aligned on 16byte boundaries. This explains why 32bit platforms were unaffected and integer and character printing worked.

I've compiled my code to assembly with:

```
gcc -W list.c -o list.S -shared -Wl,-e,my_main -S -fPIC
```

then altered the "my_main" function to be have more stack space.

**Before:**

```
my_main:
 .LFB6:
 .cfi_startproc
 pushq   %rbp
 .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
 .cfi_offset 6, -16
 movq    %rsp, %rbp
 .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
 movl    $.LC0, %eax
 movsd   .LC1(%rip), %xmm0
 movq    %rax, %rdi
 movl    $1, %eax
 call    printf
 movl    $0, %edi
 call    _exit
 .cfi_endproc
```

**After:**

```
my_main:
 .LFB6:
 .cfi_startproc
 pushq   %rbp
 .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
 .cfi_offset 6, -16
 subq    $8, %rsp ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; ADDED THIS LINE
 movq    %rsp, %rbp
 .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
 movl    $.LC0, %eax
 movsd   .LC1(%rip), %xmm0
 movq    %rax, %rdi
 movl    $1, %eax
 call    printf
 movl    $0, %edi
 call    _exit
 .cfi_endproc
```

Then I compiled this .S file by:

```
gcc list.S -o liblist.so -Wl,-e,my_main -shared
```

This fixes the issue, but I will forward this thread to the GCC and GLIBC mailing lists, as it looks like a bug.

**edit1:**

According to *noshadow* in gcc irc, this is a non standard way to do this. He said if one is to use gcc -e option, either initialize the C runtime manually, or don't use libc functions. Makes sense.

Comment: ISTR that there is an option for gcc to align the stack on larger boundaries than the default one. You could be able to use it as a work around until the bug is fixed instead of modifying the assembly.

Comment: Sounds good. Alternative way is to not use libc functions and use syscalls directly, but note this is more code and less portable.

Comment: The instructions that load single floating-point values into XMM registers do not require 16-byte alignment. They only require four-byte alignment for single-precision and eight-byte alignment for double-precision. You may have been encountering other issues, such as violating the Application Binary Interface requires for calling subroutines (might have aligned the stack incorrectly, might have failed to set a bit that indicates floating-point parameters are passed, or other problems).