# How to trigger c'tors of globals in executable shared library (.so)?

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, factory, elf

I have a shared library that I would like to make executable, similar to libc.  When the library executes, I would like it to dump a list of the names of classes that are registered with a particular abstract factory (this is C++).  I use the standard technique of registering classes with the factory through the initialization/construction of global variables.

There are several tutorials on how to make shared libraries executable ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912423/unable-to-printf-floating-point-numbers-from-executable-shared-library) and [here](http://polentino911.wordpress.com/2013/08/08/make-your-own-executable-shared-library-on-linux/), for example).  It's relatively straight forward.  However, when I try it out, I find that the entry point is executed **before** any constructors of globals are called.  In my case, this means that no classes have registered with my factory, so I have no information to print out.

I would like to either execute the entry point **after** the constructors have been called, or learn how to **trigger construction myself** from my entry-point function.  Is this possible?  Does anyone know how to go about doing this?  Perhaps there is an internal libc function that I can extern and call?

Comment: Are you in control of the entry point function code?  What exactly stops you from invoking the constructors of your global objects therein?  (Asking from ignorance.)

Comment: I can control the entry point code, but I believe that I would need a mechanism to retrieve a list of c'tors to call. This mechanism must exist since normal programs do this all the time, but I don't know how to do this myself. Perhaps I need to dig deeper into the ELF documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that I have come across a workable solution.  It is based upon techniques for creating `-nostdlib` executables (such as OS kernels).  However, our shared library still links the standard libraries in this case.  I found [this](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=34925) RaspberryPi forum thread especially useful.

The solution is to manually execute the function pointers stored in the shared library's embedded `init_array`.  The trick is to use a linker script to define pointers for accessing this array. We then `extern` these pointers in the program code. We can repeat the process for executing destructors as well.

In `test.cpp`, we have the following:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>

class Test
{
public:
    Test() { printf("Hello world!\n"); }
    ~Test() { printf("Goodbye world!\n"); }
};

Test myGlobal;  // a global class instance

extern "C"
{
// ensures linker generates executable .so (assuming x86_64)
extern const char test_interp[] __attribute__((section(".interp"))) =
    "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2";

// function walks the init_array and executes constructors
void manual_init(void)
{
    typedef void (*constructor_t)(void);
    // _manual_init_array_start and _manual_init_array_end
    // are created by linker script.
    extern constructor_t _manual_init_array_start[];
    extern constructor_t _manual_init_array_end[];

    constructor_t *fn = _manual_init_array_start;
    while(fn < _manual_init_array_end)
    {
        (*fn++)();
    }
}

// function walks the fini_array and executes destructors
void manual_fini(void)
{
    typedef void (*destructor_t)(void);
    // _manual_init_array_start and _manual_init_array_end
    // are created by linker script.
    extern destructor_t _manual_fini_array_start[];
    extern destructor_t _manual_fini_array_end[];

    destructor_t *fn = _manual_fini_array_start;
    while(fn < _manual_fini_array_end)
    {
        (*fn++)();
    }
}

// entry point for libtest.so when it is executed
void lib_entry(void)
{
    manual_init();  // call ctors
    printf("Entry point of the library!\n");
    manual_fini();  // call dtors

    _exit(0);
}
```

We need to manually define the `_manual*` pointers through a linker script. We must use the `INSERT` keyword so that don't entirely replace ld's default linker script. In a file `test.ld`, we have:

```
SECTIONS
{
    .init_array : ALIGN(4)
    {
        _manual_init_array_start = .;
        *(.init_array)
        *(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.init_array.*))
        _manual_init_array_end = .;
    }
}
INSERT AFTER .init; /* use INSERT so we don't override default linker script */

SECTIONS
{
    .fini_array : ALIGN(4)
    {
        _manual_fini_array_start = .;
        *(.fini_array)
        *(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.fini_array.*))
        _manual_fini_array_end = .;
    }
}
INSERT AFTER .fini; /* use INSERT so we don't override default linker script */
```

We must provide two parameters to the linker: (1) our linker script and (2) the entry point to our library. To compile, we do the following:

```
 g++ test.cpp -fPIC -Wl,-T,test.ld -Wl,-e,lib_entry -shared -o libtest.so
```

We get the following output when `libtest.so` is executed at the commandline:

```
$ ./libtest.so 
Hello world!
Entry point of the library!
Goodbye world!
```

I've also tried defining globals in .cpp files other than `test.cpp` that are also compiled into the shared library. The ctor calls for these globals are included in `init_array`, so they are called by `manual_init()`. The library works "like normal" when it is loaded as a regular shared library.

Comment: A much simpler solution is to link your DSO with `-pie` flag. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1451482/50617

Comment: Wow. There is _nothing_ in the gcc man page that would suggest that -pie would give me that behavior.